# Symfony 4 - No route found after installation on Mac

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I have tried to install the Symfony 4 on my Macbook Air by using Composer. I have used the below commands for installing and running Symfony application

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton symfony4

cd symfony4

composer require server --dev

php bin/console server:run
```

And then tried to access the application in http://127.0.0.1:8000/. Below is the error message

[image: Error screen]

Below image shows the error in which line and file

[image]

I am using PHP 7.2.3 and installed by using Homebrew. At the same time when I use the below command to install, Symfony welcome page appears without any error.

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton symfony4
```

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643561/symfony-4-setup-issues-router-exception/48647114#48647114

Comment: Thanks for your information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can read how to create a symfony page: https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html

Answer (score 3):

There is no default welcome page when you create new symfony flex application and there is an [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25980) and a [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/26041) already.

Everything is working fine you just don't have any pages.