# No route found for "GET /" New installation of framework Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes, installation

I have this error,this is a new fresh installation of Symfony.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643561/symfony-4-setup-issues-router-exception/48647114#48647114

Comment: bin/console debug:router   not work for me.Message:  'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sounds like you typed a space after bin?   What version of Symfony are you trying to use?  I suspect you may need to work through the setup portion of the docs.

Comment: Or maybe you are developing on a windows machine?  If so then "php bin/console" might help.

Comment: Yes i am using Windows,I've tried so many things but no success for now.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown when there isn't a matching route for the path you're trying to access, in this case "/".

You need to create a route that matches the path "/": https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html