# Error when first launching symfony 4 project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to use Symfony 4.x for a new project, I have installed composer and used it to create a new project. My php version is 7.0.10 & I have wamp as well.

In this tutorial (https://symfony.com/doc/master/setup.html), it says after you run the server "Open your browser and navigate to http://localhost:8000/". When I do so, I get a No route found for "GET /" error.

the pictures bellow display what I get as an error more precisely :

[image]

as well as

[image]

I have installed everything following the guide on their official page. I have seen this problem being discussed on github (https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/9178) but I don't understand their "quick fix" nor what they're talking about.

I want to know how to get my project running without that problem.

Thanks for any help

Comment: To start with you need at least php 7.1.3.  Surprised it even loaded.  I suspect you got Symfony 3.4 instead. And then this is a bit verbose but it explains the unexpected no route found message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643561/symfony-4-setup-issues-router-exception/48647114#48647114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s strange but It’s totally normal and the error proved that Symfony is well installed
It’s not a « compile » or « configuration » error it’s just a logical error that means you don’t have route defined at
 url / so keep learning and define a route (see [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) and you see the result)

Comment: so I basically need to define my first route?

Comment: Updated answer with doc link